# attr_reader is not calling variable

Tags: ruby

I am building a game that is having a problem when calling a method. A monster can appear and will get a randomized weapon, and if that weapon is ranged the monster gets a one-turn setback to give the player a fighting chance. When the method monsterRangedTurnSetback is called I get the error that it is trying to find attributes in nil:NilClass. I ended up tracing it back to a genWeapon function, and that the function isn't being able to be called. Hers some code to

```
def monsterRangedTurnSetback(weapon)
  attribs = weapon.attributes()
  attribs.each do |attrib|
    if attrib == "Ranged"
      return 1
    else
      return 0
    end
  end
end

def genWeapon
  weaponGen = rand(1..80)
  if weaponGen == 1 or weaponGen == 2
    weapon = GreatSword.new
    hasTwoHandedWeapon = true
  elsif weaponGen == (3..23)
    weapon = ShortSword.new
    hasTwoHandedWeapon = false
  elsif weaponGen == (24..34)
    weapon = ShortBow.new
    hasTwoHandedWeapon = true
  elsif weaponGen == (35..48)
    weapon = LongBow.new
    hasTwoHandedWeapon = true
  elsif weaponGen == (49..64)
    weapon = Dagger.new
    hasTwoHandedWeapon = false
  elsif weaponGen == (65..78)
    weapon = HandCrossbow.new
    hasTwoHandedWeapon = false
  elsif weaponGen == 79 or weaponGen == 80
    weapon = HeavyCrossbow.new
    hasTwoHandedWeapon = true
  end
  return weapon
  puts weapon.name
  sleep 2
end

class Orc
  attr_accessor :totalDamage, :totalHealth, :armorClass, :attackText, :name, 
  :turnSetback
  def initialize
    @wep = genWeapon()
    @baseDamage = 7
    @weapon = @wep
    @turnSetback = monsterRangedTurnSetback(@weapon)
    @wep = nil
    @health = 5
    @hasShield = shield(@weapon)
    @armorClass = 6
    if @hasShield == true
      @armorClass += 2
    end
    @challengeLevel = 1
    @attackText = ["Orc stabs you", "Orc slashes at you", "Orc intimidates you"]
    @name = "Orc"
  end
end

class ShortSword
  attr_reader :attributes, :name, :attackBonus
  def initialize
    @attributes = ["Melee", "1Hand"]
    attackBonus = 3
    name = "Short Sword"
  end
end
```

Yes the code goes in that order, and yes I know the monster class is allowing reading of non-existent variables. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: weapon is only being set when `weaponGen` is 1,2,79, or 80 because `weaponGen` will never equal (`==`) a `Range`. Instead of `weaponGen == (3..23)`  I think what you meant was  `(3..23).cover?(weaponGen)`. There are certainly many other issues with this code (both logically and syntactically)  but that should get you past the current one.

Comment: This is in dire need of a `case` statement or, even better, a lookup table. Also, in Ruby method definitions and calls with no arguments have their corresponding parens omitted, so you'd write `attributes` in preference to `attributes`. This makes chaining methods less syntactically messy. Likewise, variable and method names are all lower-case, upper-case letters have significant meaning in Ruby, so use `weapon_gen` in preference to `weaponGen`.

Comment: There's also code in there that's after a `return` statement which means it will never run, so it's curious why it's there. Hopefully an artifact of some earlier debugging effort.

Comment: @tadman no, I actually didn't know that. I'm still new to a lot of this, only about 1 or 2 years of experience.

Answer (score 1):

The mistake here might be that `attr_reader` cannot bind to local varaibles like `x` but only to instance variables like `@x`. In your code:

```
attr_reader :attackBonus

def initialize
  # This is a local variable that will fall out of scope once the method
  # finishes. It is not saved anywhere, simply thrown away.
  attackBonus = 3
end
```

Adding an `@` prefix to that will make it persist and be readable.

The same thing plays out in `genWeapon` where local variables are set and discarded. If you need those persisted somehow you need to include them in the return. Those properties should be part of some kind of base Weapon class anyway, where you can call `Dagger.new.two_handed?` or `Dagger.new.hands_required`.

As @engineersmnky points out there's a crippling flaw in the `genWeapon` method where `x == (1..2)` will never return true for any value of `x` that isn't literally `(1..2)`. What *would* work is `(1..2).include?(x)` or `(1..2) === x`. Since `case` uses `===` internally it makes it easy to write:

```
case (rand(1..80))
when 1..2
  GreatSword.new
when 3..23
  ShortSword.new
# ...
end
```

That's still really tedious. Instead write a lookup-table:

```
WEAPON_PROBABILITY = {
  (1..2) => GreatSword,
  (3..23) => ShortSword,
  (24..34) => ShortBow,
  (35..48) => LongBow,
  (49..64) => Dagger,
  (65..78) => HandCrossbow,
  (79..80) => HeavyCrossbow
}.flat_map do |range, type|
  range.to_a.map do |roll|
    [ roll, type ]
  end
end.to_h
```

This maps rolls to classes. Then your generator function becomes trivial:

```
def gen_weapon
  WEAPON_PROBABILITY[rand(1..80)].new
end
```

Making use of Ruby's "everything is an object" principle to make look-up tables of classes dramatically simplifies things and can make the code more immediately understandable. Always try to steer your program towards defining things in terms of *data* instead of *procedures* whenever you can.

Comment: @engineersmnky This code is really dizzying, I'm doing my best!

Comment: Since you are posting an answer might as well re iterate my comment which seems to be the current issue because `genWeapon` will return `nil` the majority of the time and then `monsterRangedTurnSetback` will error out

Comment: That's a very good observation. I had a partial fix ready for that but thought it was over-complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to revisit how you define some of these classes. Perhaps even include the `turn_delay` as a method on the Weapon class. Here's how I might refactor this to inherit specialized weapons from a weapon parent class:

```
class Weapon
  attr_reader :attributes, :name, :attack_bonus

  def initialize
    @attributes = []
  end

  def turn_delay?
    @attributes.include? :ranged
  end

  def two_handed?
    @attributes.include? :two_hand
  end
end

class ShortSword < Weapon
  def initialize
    @attributes = %i(melee one_hand)
    @attack_bonus = 3
    @name = 'Short Sword'
  end
end

class LongBow < Weapon
  def initialize
    @attributes = %i(ranged)
    @attack_bonus = 10
    @name = 'Long Bow'
  end
end

bow = LongBow.new
puts bow.name
puts bow.turn_delay?

sword = ShortSword.new
puts sword.name
puts sword.turn_delay?
```

Output:

```
Long Bow
true
Short Sword
false
```

I had too much fun with this, a large number of weapons could become cumbersome to write class definitions for. Since you picked Ruby, you can embrace some meta programming and quickly whip up new weapons by using the following (requires you've defined that base `Weapon` class:

```
[
  { klass: 'BroadSword', attributes: [:melee, :two_hand], attack_bonus: 20, name: 'Broad Sword' },
  { klass: 'Dagger', attributes: [:melee, :one_hand], attack_bonus: 1, name: 'Dagger' },
  { klass: 'ShortBow', attributes: [:ranged], attack_bonus: 5, name: 'Short Bow' },
].each do |obj|
  eval <<WEAPON
  class #{obj[:klass]} < Weapon
    def initialize
      @attributes = #{obj[:attributes]}
      @name = '#{obj[:name]}'
      @attack_bonus = #{obj[:attack_bonus]}
    end
  end
WEAPON
end
```

Then:

```
bs = BroadSword.new
puts bs.name
puts bs.two_handed?

Broad Sword
true
```

Comment: In the second case you could always use a Json or a yml file to store all of your weapons to make for custom weapons and easy modifications. Nicely done on the refactor

Comment: Since I am relatively new would you mind explaining what the lines eval<<WEAPON and WEAPON do? Thanks for the answer as well I'm going to try it now?

Comment: Sure eval basically evaluates (executes) the code between the delimiters and injects it into the current context. The "WEAPON" terms are basically just text delimiters, they indicate where to start and stop the evaluation. https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-eval

Comment: Whenever I run this I get an error, "Wrong number of arguments(given 0, expected 1..4)"